# Extracting the "p adj" values from a TukeyHSD test

Tags: r

With a dummy data set:

```
Species      Var1     Var2   Var3
   a          1         2      3
   a          4         5      6 
   b          7         8      9
   b          10       11      12
```

I have multiple Species and about 50 Variables (Var50). I would like to perform a One-way Anova on the paired grouping variable (Species) for each response variable and get the output of frequencies that are statistically significant at the 95% CI, for example. I began writing a function to do this as follows:

```
data<-read.table("example.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
function(y){
for(y in 2:50)
anova.r<-aov(y~Species, data = data)
result<-TukeyHSD(anova.r, conf.level = 0.95) 
f.result ## I cannot figure out how to extract the "p adj" from the results

f.result<-sum(prob.result>=0.05)
write.table(f.result, file = "anova95.csv", sep = ",",
        col.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
}
```

Ultimately, I would like the final table (dummy answers) to look like

```
                     Var1   Var2   Var3......Var50 
Frequency at 95% CI   106    200    45         246
```

I know I can use `[[]]` to access data within the results for the Tukey test. I have tried to use `tukey.results[[1]][,1]` up to `tukey.results[[1]][,3]` to no avail. `tukey.results[[1]]` returns all the columns from the Tukey test.

Also, I am thinking I might have to use `cbind` somewhere in the function to get the data in their respective columns. OR I was thinking it would be possible to use the `apply` command but I don't know how to keep the grouping variable constant while varying the response variable at every iteration.

Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `result$Species[4]` will give you the "p adj"

Comment: @eddi, thanks for the suggestion. Tried it but I only get a value (not the fourth value in the "p adj" neither).

Comment: just look at what `result$Species` is and you should see what you want there; if you don't, then I'm guessing your example is not representative of your real problem

Comment: `result$Species` gives all the expected values. The first few lines are      `diff         lwr        upr     p adj
A oil palm2-A oil palm1      -0.021441963 -0.06055280 0.01766887 0.8704602
AfricanOilPalm_1-A oil palm1 -0.001384416 -0.04049525 0.03772642 1.0000000
AfricanOilPalm_2-A oil palm1 -0.017210672 -0.05632151 0.02190016 0.9776883`.  Could the problem be the structure of `result`? The structure I have is `str(result$Species)`
 `num [1:120, 1:4]`

Comment: try `result$Species[,'p.adj']` or `result$Species[, 4]`

Comment: Thanks eddi, `result$Species[, 4]` worked a bit, but to get the list of pairwise comparisons in one column and the respective "p adj" values in another, I had to use `melt(result$Species[, 4])` from the `reshape` package.... Thanks a million though. Now I have to continue with the function to try get my end result. Thanks once again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this if you are also looking for variables:

```
summary(fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks))
kk<-TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension", ordered = TRUE)
kk$tension
result<-data.frame( kk$tension)
result["p.adj"]

            p.adj
M-H 0.447421021
L-H 0.001121788
L-M 0.033626219
```

Comment: thanks for the example and help. However when I try the same with my data I get `[1] NA` as the answer. Unlike the `data = warpbreaks` dataset, my data only has one set of factor variables. I'm not sure if this would make a difference.

Comment: You probably need to `dput` the representative data for reproducibility. Before that make sure you understand the rationale and requirements for use of the `aov`.

Comment: I do understand the rationale and requirements of the `aov`. I think I may have too many packages open, so I will try on another computer. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @Metrics thus this method work for one-way anova? When I tried this on my data it only returned null. I am trying to make my tukey result easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The answer did not work on my system. Here is my solution starting with the code Metrics provided.

```
 summary(fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks))
 kk<-TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension", ordered = TRUE)
 kk<-kk$tension          #strips off some headers in kk
 kk<-as.data.frame(kk)   #converts to data frame
 kk<-kk$'p adj'          #selects relevant output
 print(kk)               #to check answer
```